# Creating array list of java objects from JSON URL with Gson

Tags: java, json, list, parsing, gson

I am able to parse the following data into a java object:

```
{
    "name": "testname",
    "address": "1337 455 ftw",
    "type": "sometype",
    "notes": "cheers mate"
}
```

using this code:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        URL objectGet = new URL("http://10.0.0.4/file.json");

        URLConnection yc = objectGet.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try {
            DataO data = new Gson().fromJson(in, DataO.class);

            System.out.println(data.getName());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }      
}
```

But now I want to store a list of these objects out of the following JSON String:

```
[
    {
        "name": "testname",
        "address": "1337 455 ftw",
        "type": "sometype",
        "notes": "cheers mate"
    },
    {
        "name": "SumYumStuff",
        "address": "no need",
        "type": "clunkdroid",
        "notes": "Very inefficient but high specs so no problem."
    }
]
```

Could someone help me modify my code to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You could specify the type to deserialize into as an array or as a collection.

As Array:

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Data0[] data = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), Data0[].class);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(data));
  }
}

class Data0
{
  String name;
  String address;
  String type;
  String notes;
}
```

As List:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    List<Data0> data = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), new TypeToken<List<Data0>>(){}.getType());
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(data));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce, this is perfect.  I ended up going with the List, but tried the Array out also and they both worked.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look in the [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Limitations) indicates that this might not be possible since the deserializer doesn't know the type of the elements since you could have elements of different types in the array.

> Collections Limitations
>
> Can serialize collection of arbitrary objects but can not deserialize
>   from it Because there is no way for the user to indicate the type of
>   the resulting object While deserializing, Collection must be of a
>   specific generic type

Comment: In the example question, I don't see any indication that the list could contain components of different types (or of different subtypes of a common parent type).  Gson does have built-in handling for deserializing into a list or array of same-typed things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Any suggestions as to how would I work around this?

Should I be using a different library to parse the Json?
Should I be looking into this 'TypeToken' mentioned in the user guide you linked to?